# How to configure https support in 443 for apache AND node?

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, https, reverse-proxy

Actual state:

http://www.example.com/mypage ***apache http: OK!***
  https://www.example.com/mypage ***apache https: OK!***

http://www.example.com:8000 ***node http: OK!***
  https://www.example.com:8000 ***node https: Not working (still)***

I've tried to modify node program to be

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(app);

https.createServer({ 
        key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem"),
        ca: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem")
}, app).listen(443);
```

The obvious problem here is that apache is ALREADY listenning to port 443, then

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::443
```

Is there a way to use Apache 443 to serve SSL for node?

Answer (score 7):

You can only bind one process to a given port on your server.

That said, the *correct* way to do this is to have Apache listen on 443, then use mod_proxy to forward the traffic to nodejs either on an HTTP port (not w/ SSL, but you're only talking across localhost) or on a unix socket.

A good example of how to do that with port 80/HTTP is here: http://blog.podrezo.com/making-node-js-work-with-apache/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName pastebin.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.pastebin.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/pastebinjs/
  Options -Indexes
  ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html

  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyPass /maintenance.html !
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

But the theory is the same if you add the Proxy* lines to your existing HTTPS endpoint.

Comment: Would this go in httpd.conf file? @Paul

Comment: @FabricioG it can, but generally I'd suggest using a site-level .conf file and including it in httpd.conf using the Include directive.

Comment: The link provided in this answer is broken.

Answer (score 2):

To have two servers, Apache and node.js serving on port 443, the common solution is to use a reverse proxy.

Apache can be configured to use mod_proxy, nodejs also has proxy configurations, and there are external programs dedicated to this job.

I would recommend using haproxy, to listen on ports 80 and 443, and make the necessary rules to forward requests to the servers of your choice.
Then, apache can listen on 6080 and 6443, node can listen on 8080 and 8443 for example.

That way, apache and nodejs can be fairly untouched - except for modifying listening ports - and haproxy is transparent and flexible with access control lists. You can use ssl for all *443 ports.

Answer (score 1):

Your node HTTPS server can run on any port - let's say 9090 instead of the 443 you have set. Use Apache to redirect any traffic that comes in https://example.com to your node https server listening on 9090.

Check out apache reverse-proxy for more information on how to set this up :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need to import SSL Files or keys in node server. (Follow my steps to run both apache and node servers in SSL). Hope you already configured SSL in **Apache** server

**Node(Express)**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
```

Open **httpd.conf** in server and add **ProxyPass** line as u want

```
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:3000/
```

> DONT FOGOT TO RESTART THE HTTP SERVICE

http://www.example.com/mypage apache http: OK!

https://www.example.com/mypage apache https: OK!

http://www.example.com/api/ node http: OK!

https://www.example.com/api/ node https: IT WORKKS !!!